# storing values derived in a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please I need you guys help. I want do some calculations on the values that will be obtained from a loop but the calculation will depend on the last value the loop will compute. How do I store these values until the last value is computed by the loop and use the outcome to do further calculation on the previous values. Please I need a demonstrating example

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: Or post the code in your question. Off site links are nice but not as good as in post code.

Comment: I have no idea of how to go about it, that's why I need help.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped alot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you could store every single value from the loop like this:

```
//First, make an empty array.
var values = [];

//Then, make your loop. This loop runs 50 times, but
//you can make it run however many times you want.
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  //This is where your loop does something with "i".
  //You can do whatever you want with it, but I've chosen to square it.
  values[i] = i * i;
}
//Now, "values" is an array with every calculation from the loop.
//Make another for loop, where "i" counts up to the length of "values".
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  //The last result of the first loop is values[values.length - 1].
  //here, do what you want with the values. I have chosen to divide each
  //value by the last calculation of the function.
  values[i] = values[i] / values[values.length - 1];
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Seriously? Why would you answer a question as badly written as this one?  Do not answer bad questions, it only encourages them to ask more.  There are too many worthless questions as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment though, will try and simplify my questions next time